# Can I use command blocks to teleport a player who died?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to detect if a player has died and teleport that one to location XY and give the other team a point.

I can detect if a player has died with `testfor @a[score_HEALTH=1]` applied to a redstone pulse, but that just outputs a signal *if* a player has died, not who has died.

Is there a way to detect which player has died? Is there a way to use the detected player who has died as an argument in the next command block, like `/tp @f X Y Z`, where `@f` stands for the found player of the last command block?

If nothing of that works, are there workarounds?

Comment: Could you just set the spawn point to a certain place, which will land them on a pressure plate that teleports them to a place based on their team, and adds a point to the other team?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any selector arguments you use in `testfor` can be used in `tp`. Like so:

```
1.7 to 1.12: /tp @a[score_HEALTH=1] X Y Z
1.13+:       /tp @a[scores={HEALTH=..1}] X Y Z
```

There are problems with using low health to check for death. Instead, I'd recommend adding a `deaths` scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

This score will get set to 1 when a player dies (automatic, because of the type of objective), your commands can teleport players with a `deaths` score of 1 and then set it back to 0 (so the player isn't repeatedly teleported).

The following commands are a full solution, including the team score incrementing, for 1.13+:

```
tp @a[scores={deaths=1..}] 73 10 31
execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..},team=red] run scoreboard players add blue points 1
execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..},team=blue] run scoreboard players add red points 1
scoreboard players set @a deaths 0
```

Comment: after i saw the other - far shorter - answer i figured all that stuff out myself. Still thanks. Good description on how to accomplish it!

Comment: @Shiuyin If the other answer was helpful at all, you should give it an upvote.

Comment: @ SevenSidedDie: Done.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked much with team scoreboard stuff, but the teleport should just be

```
/tp @p[score_HEALTH=1] X Y Z
```

@a is used to find all players matching some criteria; @p only finds one at a time, but let's you use that player's name inside other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use `/setworldspawn` unless you're doing a team based game then yea, listen to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

the easyest thing to do is to reset the players spawnpoint using commandblocks
as soon as they respawn they will appear in the set location