# Can I use command blocks to teleport a player who died and give them a point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've read and tried [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/can-i-use-command-blocks-to-teleport-a-player-who-died) but I still can't figure out why instead of teleporting me when I die, it instantly teleported me to the point and didn't let me move! I don't know what I did wrong. I exactly copied what the accepted answer said, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Please include a screenshot

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I solved it, sorry

Comment: if you solved it could you include that as an answer or mark the person who gave you teh correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Please do not copy and paste the accepted answer 1:1 without filling the placeholders and without creating the scoreboards before usage.

You need to replace placeholders such as `X-cord` with the actual X-cooridinate. You can see the world cooridinates when you press `F3`.

Please mind, that you need to create the scoreboars are shown in the answer *before* you try to add values to them.

You can create scoreboards using this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add <name> <criteria> [display name...]
```

User [colorfusion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/54474/colorfusion) shows this [inside of his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129308/107951) like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

The argument `deathCount` tells the scoreboard to automatically count the amount of player-deaths.

Comment: I think the bigger issue was the missing HEALTH objective.